# Should I switch to 64bit Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 64bit vs 32bit](https://superuser.com/questions/63799/ubuntu-64bit-vs-32bit)

I've been using 32 bit Ubuntu for the last couple of years on my development machine.

I generally write web apps in php.

I would like to use a 64 bit OS for the obvious reasons but wonder if there are any Got-Ya's that I should know about.

For those that are using a 64 bit version of Ubuntu, is it as straight forward as using the 32 bit version, or are there issues that one needs to be aware of?

Comment: Duplicate anyhow, like for example "Ubuntu 64bit vs 32bit" at http://superuser.com/questions/63799/ubuntu-64bit-vs-32bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the 64bit edition of Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala and haven't had any problems. Even flash worked right away.

Look at this for a [32 vs 64 bit benchmark of Ubuntu 9.04](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/ubuntu-904-32-bit-vs-64-bit-benchmarks).

Answer (score 1):

I first tried 64bit ubuntu with the Hardy Heron release, the only issues I found were to do with the flash plugin

Found this link documenting any issues, but I think most if not all are resolved

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=368607