# Will all 32 - bit applications work on a 64 - bit Operating System?

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

Will all 32 - bit applications work on a 64 - bit  windows 7 Operating System?

Comment: See Mr Fooz's and romkyns' answers on http://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems

Comment: @Diago - I had searched this question and  i am not able to find out . So i have asked this . But i think its most of answer .. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 (64-bit) has 32-bit emulation layer and all applications that work in Windows 7 (32-bit) will work with 64-bit version also.

However, 32-bit drivers will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Most will - some which make specific API calls may not (such as Anti Virus, Firewall, drivers or other "high level" software).