# Can we run a 32 bit Windows7 software onto a 64 bit Windows7?

Tags: windows, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will all 32 - bit applications work on a 64 - bit Operating System?](https://superuser.com/questions/63949/will-all-32-bit-applications-work-on-a-64-bit-operating-system)

If so, how? And can we convert 64 bit Windows to 32 bit Windows operating system?

Comment: Yes, you just run it and it works, there's no magic required!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can run 32-bit software on 64-bit Windows 7.

No, as far as I know, you can't boot a 64-bit Windows in exclusively 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [natively](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-windows7-vista64-support-32bit-applications.htm).

Alternatively, if there's any software that doesn't work, you can always install it inside [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx)

> As MarkM pointed in the comments,
>   Windows XP mode is only supported in
>   Proffessional, Enterprise and Ultimate
>   editions; if you have none, you can
>   follow [this guide](http://lifehacker.com/#!5478287/create-your-own-xp-mode-for-any-version-of-windows) to create a
>   windows xp mode like - virtual machine

Comment: XP mode only installs on Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate editions. Many users have Home Premium, which is not eligible for XP mode.

Comment: @MarkM You are right, I added more information on the matter. Thanks