# Why does Windows 7 64-bit require more memory than 32-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, performance, memory, 32-bit

Why does Windows 7 64-bit require more memory than 32-bit, according to the upgrade advisor?

Comment: Whilst Win7 and software in general will need a little more memory due to the larger size of a pointer, it's not *that* different. The ‘recommended’ 1GB for 32-bit and 2GB for 64-bit Win7 is absolute fantasy.

Comment: @bobince - Thanks for the comment.  Any idea of why the recommendation is there?

Answer (score 8):

I don't have any special information about the upgrade advisor, but here are a couple possibilities:

1. There's not much reason to use 64-bit unless you're going to have more than 3GB of RAM, as the extra address space won't do much for you.  There are some special-case reasons, like high security applications or certain media processing, but in general memory address space is the reason to use a 64-bit OS at the moment.
2. 64-bit OSes DO use more space to store memory addresses, as each address is generally twice as long (this isn't totally precise, but a generalization here will do).  This means that storing the locations of data in memory takes more memory itself.  Again, however, this isn't really a reason *not* to use a 64-bit OS, because if you are using one you are probably taking advantage of its increased address space anyway with a decent amount of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  There is a good summary of 32 vs 64 bit here:

http://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems/56586#56586

Answer (score 4):

Reasons behind this might be:

- this is meant to act as a kind of advisory on which version to  choose. If you have 1 GB of RAM, you are quite unlikely to ever upgrade the system to more then 2 GB, therefore 64b would have no benefits for you.
- the actual system requirements as given by those who have really tested the OS might look something like *"Win7 x86 edition requires 0.8 GB RAM, x64 edition requires 1.1 GB of RAM"*. As those numbers are always rounded up to a nearest GB, you end with 1 GB and 2 GB even.

I think x64 Win7 would run on 1 GB very similar to x86 edition. There is a little difference caused by larger pointer size, but it definitely will not cause memory consumption to grow more than 20 %, but unless you have more RAM, there is very little reason to use 64b OS.

That said, there might be other situations where x64 edition will really need to a lot more memory. Consider scenario where you run multiple applications, some of them are 64b, others are 32b. Each application requires DLLs which match its bit-ness - hence you will also need many components to be loaded twice, 32b and 64b, or at least to have 32b-64b translation layers loaded instead of them.