# What are the differences in using 32 bit and 64 bit Windows 10 on 2GB RAM?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, 64-bit, 32-bit

The system has only 2 GB of soldered RAM and can't be upgraded. It is a Intel Celeron processor. A similar system works fine with 32 bit of Windows.
I plan to use the "Bash On Linux" on windows. It first came on 64 bits. I do not know if 32 bit supports it.

I prefer Chrome (and have usually 20+ tabs open) and not Firefox (which uses significantly less RAM).

My primary usage comprises programming (on light editors mostly) and lots of tabs open in the browser.

CPU does support 64 bit. Celeron 2840: http://ark.intel.com/products/82103/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2840-1M-Cache-up-to-2_58-GHz

Comment: You must also re-check your CPU capabilities (look for EM64T support), some of old CPU does not support a 64-bit.

Comment: This is the CPU: http://ark.intel.com/products/82103/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2840-1M-Cache-up-to-2_58-GHz

Comment: All versions of Windows 10 Version 1607 support the new Linux a subsystem.

Comment: @Ramhound This is not a duplicate question. The linked question doesn't talk about Windows 10. My question talks about Windows 10 (which seems to take different amount of resources than Windows 8). My main concerns are Linux Subsystem and Chrome. It's not present in the linked question. Please look into it again. Thank you :)

Comment: @Mokubai This is not a duplicate of the linked question. Please refer to the above comment. Thank you.

Comment: @aste123 I don't agree.  Windows x64 is Windows x64 there is nothing special about Windows 10 64-bit that would change anything that the duplicate questions answer stated

Comment: @aste123 then you need to make your question more specific.  Are you looking to find out whether you can use the Linux subsystem or to find out if Chrome will be usable? Listing the specific differences per the question in your title is either too broad or is answered by the duplicate and it's duplicates, and there are no other queries in your body. "Is the bash system available on 32-bit?" Would be good and specific, but if you have a similar system as your body suggests then you can easily find out. What are you actually trying to find out? Your question feels too vague as it stands.

Comment: @Mokubai I don't own the other 32 bit system. I can't install softwares on it. Your comment does reflect the problem that my question might be unclear. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

To make it simple, 64Bit does not only mean that you are able to use more then ~3gb ram. 64bit comes with a few more features which most software and also windows is already taking advantage of. Therefore it would best to go with 64Bit even though you only have 2gb RAM. You will not notice the difference to 32 bit anyway.

Comment: 64-bit OS will use more RAM (see [Why does Windows 7 64-bit require more memory than 32-bit?](http://superuser.com/q/77281/194694)), for 2 GB RAM system that could make a difference.

Comment: Won't it bog down the system with only 2GB

Comment: If you want some extra info, check this LTT video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IknbgnJLSRY It sums up the main differences between 32, and 64 bit. But I do honestly think that 2GB of RAM is not enough, certainly if you have 20+ tabs open. I usually do that to, and I have 16GB of RAM, but I use an extension called 'The Great Suspender' which clears the tab out of the RAM after a while.