# Do I have 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have manually installed Windows 7 Ultimate on my AMD on 32-bit, but I am not sure if I have 32 or 64 bit.

My Windows 7 system (CP) tells me I have a 32-bit OS, but that my processor is a AMD Athlon64.

So, do I have a 32 or 64 bit?

Is it better to use 64 bit? I don't think so; a lot of programs tell at their websites 'only 32-bit'. It still works, but that would be because I have installed Windows 7 as 32-bit.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: http://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems

Comment: @mehper Excellent link!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a 32-bit OS on 64-bit capable hardware.

Basically, this means you CAN use a 64-bit OS, but you don't have to. There's really little point unless you have more than 3 GB of RAM. Compatibility issues are mainly a thing of the past, too - 64-bit architecture can emulate 32-bit architecture just fine in the vast, vast majority of cases.

Comment: Key point here is `emulate` which is **SLOWER**

Comment: `emulate` is perhaps not the right word. It's fast. Very fast. You won't notice the difference sort of fast.

Comment: @Jakub not slower in a way you're likely to be aware of.

Comment: I agree, emulate is too strong a word.  The problem here is that these days processors have a command dispatcher that breaks down instructions into micro ops, the x86 and even x86_64 cores the OS sees could effectively both "emulated" features of a completely different execution core.  I think the 64 bit places an extra burden on the CPU, but I don't believe that the 32 bit "emulation" imposes *any* speed loss.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro-operation

Comment: thank you! I think i'll leave it at 32bit. i've got not much ram, 1 GB. I don't think i want 64 bit :)

Comment: Good plan! Remember, though, if you ever want to add more RAM, your processor certainly isn't stopping you :)

Answer (score 2):

You have 32-bit Windows and a 64-bit processor. You should be looking for 32-bit programs if you're installing anything. Mainstream 64-bit chips can run 64-bit and 32-bit operating systems. Unless you have 4GB memory or more, there isn't much need for you to have a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article available [here](http://www.wadespires.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/32bit_versus_64bit_amd64.pdf) (PDF) which goes into a little detail about the difference between 32bit and 64bit AMD processors which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main advantage to using a 64-bit OS comes when you do computational intensive tasks (video processing, compiling, 3D rendering, etc.).

Your normal day-to-day usage such as web browsing and email will be the same on either a 32-bit or 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

GRC.com has a great little utility, **[Securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm)**, that will tell you if your CPU is 64-bit, as well as a couple other useful details.  No installer, small download, highly recommended.