# 64bit OS with only 2gb of RAM viable?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I see laptops being sold with as little as 2gb of RAM yet with a 64bit operating systems (Windows7). I cant see the advantages nor reasoning behind this. Discuss.

Comment: Do they say it's 64bit? Windows 7 is available in 32-bit versions as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is a QA site not a discussion site, so discussing it isn't going to happen.

There are certain advantages to using a 64 bit OS aside from being able to address more memory, for example:

> - Some operating systems reserve portions of process address space for
>     OS use, effectively reducing the total
>     address space available for mapping
>     memory for user programs. For
>     instance, Windows XP DLLs and other
>     user mode OS components are mapped
>     into each process's address space,
>     leaving only 2 to 3 GB (depending on
>     the settings) address space available.
>     This limit is currently much higher on
>     64-bit operating systems and does not
>     realistically restrict memory usage.
> - Memory-mapped files are becoming more difficult to implement in 32-bit
>     architectures, especially due to the
>     introduction of relatively cheap
>     recordable DVD technology. A 4 GB file
>     is no longer uncommon, and such large
>     files cannot be memory mapped easily
>     to 32-bit architectures; only a region
>     of the file can be mapped into the
>     address space, and to access such a
>     file by memory mapping, those regions
>     will have to be mapped into and out of
>     the address space as needed. This is a
>     problem, as memory mapping remains one
>     of the most efficient disk-to-memory
>     methods, when properly implemented by
>     the OS.
> - Some programs such as data encryption software can benefit
>     greatly from 64-bit registers (if the
>     software is 64-bit compiled) and
>     effectively execute 3 to 5 times
>     faster on 64-bit than on 32-bit.
> - Some complex numerical analysis algorithms are limited in their
>     precision by the errors that can creep
>     in because not all floating point
>     numbers can be accurately represented
>     with a small number of bits. Creeping
>     inaccuracies can lead to incorrect
>     results, often leading to attempts to
>     divide by zero, or to not identify two
>     quantities as being identical for
>     practical purposes. International
>     Computers Limited added 128-bit
>     support to the ICL 2900 Series in 1974
>     largely as a result of requests from
>     the scientific community.

ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#Pros_and_cons

Also, these days there aren't really many issues with a 64 bit OS unlike the old days, when driver compatibility etc. was a big problem.

One other possible reason they might decide to sell a machine with a 64 bit OS is, for example, if they offer various different options on the laptop, for example a 2GB of RAM version and a 4GB of RAM version, it's easier to just load the same software on both than separate OS's per model.

More here: [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is that you can put in another couple of GB, and use all of it, without having to reinstall the OS - which is a lot of time and effort. It gives you future expansion possibilities that a 32bit OS doesn't.

Comment: +1 that's pretty much the only reason i can see.

Comment: There are many more reasons than just this, to use a 64 bit OS.

Comment: yep, exactly as many reasons as there are programs that explicitely require a 64-bit OS of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install 64 bit OS with 2GB ram. There just isn't much point to doing so.

Comment: There are other reasons to use a 64-bit OS than access to RAM.  Read through this comparison of a system with 32-bit OS vs. 64-bit OS:  http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=asus_eee_1201n&num=1

Comment: Answer is perfectly acceptable, although a bit outdated. Three years ago this would have been right on the money +1. I don't believe in downvotes for incorrect answers as long as they aren't spam.

Comment: Yes. That is true.  Certain tasks will run faster using 64 bit processes however, some will not be faster, in fact, some tasks will run slower.  Personally, I would go with 64 bit, but if you need to run older software, or use older hardware, the drivers/software may not work in 64 bit operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage is that the manufacturer doesn't have to support any 32 bit systems.  It's one less configuration for them to track, support, update drivers for.  I've noticed a lot of the consumer systems from HP/Dell, etc. are only available with 64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply: a 64 bit OS is very rarely slower, uses very little more RAM, and is often significantly faster.  Mostly this is because x86_64 has many more registers than x86, and therefore the compiler has a much easier job optimising code.  Often the code gets smaller.  Combine that with the advantages of 64 bit addressing, and you get a better system as a result.  The only cost is that sometimes you might not be able to find a driver for some old or exotic hardware.