# what OS type to use

Tags: 64-bit, operating-systems, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

Hi there

On a Intel Core Duo system with 4GB or RAM , do I have to use a x64 or a x86 operating system?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems.  You don't **have** to use one or the other, unless you are limited to 32-bit only by your processor, but then you probably wouldn't have the question, so I'm assuming that's not it.

Comment: 64Bit, of course.