# advantage of 64 bit os on system with only 2Gb

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

Im using windows 7 ultimate 32-bit. With 64-bit processor. Will I get any performance benefits if ever I upgrade to 64-bit windows 7, with the same memory(ram) of 2Gb. The same hdd size 250Gb

Comment: For better understanding, I strictly recommend you to read all answers on this page: http://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If, you will see a slight performance decrease (as 64Bit pointers take more memory than 32Bit ones)

Answer (score 0):

Only with some very heavy scientific or mathematical applications, due to the increased count and size of the "base" registers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no discernible performance increase in your case, but note that 64-bit systems have additional security features such as [hardware-enforced DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention#Hardware_enforcement) that is not available on 32-bit systems.

Comment: Yes it is. It just needs a PAE kernel such as provided with XP SP2 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends completely on what you are doing with it. Math and Processor intensive things will benefit because of native 64bit maths and the extra registers that come with Long Mode(64 bit mode).

Also, if you run in 64 bit mode then programs can automatically take advantage of the "base line" of 64 bit processors, which includes SSE, recent CPU opcode additions, etc. Where as the "base line" of 32 bit processors is grim. Not even an FPU is guaranteed for true 386s.

Now then 64bit mode does take more memory, especially for Windows 7 where the minimum for 32 bit is 1G and minimum for 64bit is 2G. It just depends on what you intend on doing as to say if it is worth it or not.