# Is there any disadvantage to running a 64 bit OS on a low memory system?

Tags: memory, 64-bit, operating-systems, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [advantage of 64 bit os on system with only 2Gb](https://superuser.com/questions/145755/advantage-of-64-bit-os-on-system-with-only-2gb)

Is there any disadvantages in running a 64 bit OS on a low memory system, say 2GB of RAM or less?  Would there be any advantage in running a 32 bit OS instead?

Obviously, the ability to run 32 or 64 bit applications on a 64 bit OS is one advantage, are there any others?

Answer (score 1):

The main disadvantage is that 64-bit code uses more memory (due to the length of memory addresses taking up twice as much space). So, all else being equal, a 64-bit OS will use more memory and potentially run slower overall due to less memory being available for programs to use.

Answer (score 0):

Forward compatibility. Eventually 64bit should completely supersede 32bit and it is more likely a 64bit OS will be upgradeable. Windows (for example) currently does not allow in place upgrades of 32bit versions to 64bit versions. Of course if this machine is not going to last that long it may be a moot point.