# buying a computer wondering about the pit falls of haveing a 64 bit OS

Tags: operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

I am getting a custom laptop,  I only do .net development, I don't play games or download gbs of video/music.  I just want a fast computer.  Right now in order to get 8gbs of ram I have to have the 64 bit version of 7.  I need to know the following: What pitfalls could I encounter.  I know a lot of apps out there are not 64 bit apps and only come in 32 bit version.  Business Intelligence Development Studio is a good example.

Comment: this site would probably have a lot more users if the admins didnt go around closing every question that is similar and then call it a duplicate

Comment: Then explain why your question is not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32bit apps run just fine on 64bit windows.  About the only reason not to go 64bit is drivers - sometimes you'll have a harder time finding the 64bit driver for your system.  As this is a new laptop, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: so getting the 32 bit version of visual web developer will probably run just fine then?

Comment: @bil: There isn't a 64-bit version anyway.