# Windows 7 professional 32-bit on a i5 machine, good or bad?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, multi-boot, intel-core-i5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

I've got an i5 laptop which came with Windows 7 home premium.I wanted to use the professional version and before doing my dual booting with Ubuntu, I've picked up my Windows 7 professional CD and went again and install it.  I've realized later that the version I've had was a 32 bits version.

Now I'm wondering what are the implications? will I loose in processing power?speed? or whatever? I planned to start development and I want to find out from you guys before I start installing visual studio and netbeans etc...

.

Comment: thanks i think the responses provided there were as clear as possible to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details are covered in the duplicate comment provided by Thiago.

In short, 64 bit is preferable, if you have the install media for it. You can normally use your 32 bit Windows serial key to install the 64 bit version of the same edition as well.

Comment: The question posed doesn't provide you enough information to make the statement that 64bit is preferable.  And your comment regarding the serial number doesn't take into account the various ways it is possible to get Windows 7 licensing and thus is only correct in some instances.

Answer (score 0):

IT really depends on how much ram you have, what apps you will run ETC.

If you have 3.5 or so RAM or more, 7x86 will not be able to use it all.

Comment: have 4GB Ram, thinking about upgrading to 8.thanks