# What's the Best Practice reinstalling windows 7 on a dual boot with ubuntu 11.04

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub, multi-boot, reinstall

I've posted a question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/286295/windows-7-professional-32-bit-on-a-i5-machine-good-or-bad/286303) that I have a 32bits windows 7 on a dual boot machine with ubuntu 10.04 upgraded to 11.04. From the responses I had from the questions, I decided to reinstall the windows 7 but this time a 64bits version.

I've install the grub on the first section of the HDD on which ubuntu is install, meaning the 2nd Drive.

I still want guidance before I proceed.

What would you suggest me as best way to achieve that without disturbing the boot loading.

thank you for reading this.

Comment: can i have an explanation for the down vote? please explain!! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Windows 7 on the first HDD then you're going to get the Windows 7 Bootloader, and the bootloader on the second HDD will stay intact.

I have the exact same installation as you (Win7 on one drive, and Ubuntu on the other)

What I did was download and install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) then just create an entry for Ubuntu, this will give you the Grub boot loader when you select the Ubuntu entry.

If you want Grub to boot first then I would suggest booting your Second HDD as the boot device in your BIOS then re-install grub from Ubuntu to get the Windows 7 Bootloader entered into the Grub List.

Comment: thanks for the answer.that brings the question of windows 7 bootloader vs grub. which is preferable, or it just doesn't matter

Comment: In a way I prefer the Windows 7 one as it's simple, the Grub one can be useful as it provides a detailed list of ways to access your OS.