# 32 vs 64 bits... what's the big deal?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, 32-bit

Why is it considered to be such a big deal to have a 64-bit computer?  Why does it "change everything?"  Why do applications need to be designed differently between 32- and 64-bit platforms?

And, on OS X, how do you find which one you have!?

Comment: @Moab; Alas, we have dozens of duplicates by now!

Comment: possible duplicate of [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](http://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)