# Can I install 64 bit Windows 7 or 8on system with 3gb ram?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For a PC with 1GB RAM, should I install 32 Bit or 64 Bit Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/337373/for-a-pc-with-1gb-ram-should-i-install-32-bit-or-64-bit-windows-7)

Can I install 64 bit Windows 7 or 8  on system with 3gb ram ? Its a laptop with Core2Duo processor .

Comment: Short answer: Yes

Comment: What makes you think you shouldn't?  That's what I'm curious about.  Is it the fact that the system only has 3gb of Ram that makes you think you shouldn't?

Comment: I meant will it run fine and will get the 64 bit performance on 3gb ram or will I need 4gb ram for real 64 bit experience ?

Comment: "64 bit performance" should be about the same as "32 bit performance".

Comment: The 64-bit performance depends on what applications you run. For office/internet work there isn't much difference, but for audio/video, applications that do heavy mathematical processing, etc... the performance can be better.

Comment: For most people "64-bit performance" with Windows means being able to install and make use of more that 3 GB of ram at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. [All Core 2 Duo CPUs support 64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Intel_64_implementations). From Wikipedia:

> Intel Core 2 (including Mobile processors since "Merom")

Answer (score 1):

From the [Microsoft minimum specs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements), you'll need at least 2GB, which you have. You might notice a modest performance increase from 64 bit, but it won't be huge.

Of course, the more RAM, the better!