# Win 7 32 bit vs 64 bit for VS2010 and SQL server

Tags: operating-systems, 32-bit, hardware-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

My planning is to buy a machine having Intel I5 processor for web development using VS2010 and SQL server(latest version). Now Which OS 32bit or 64bit would be better keeping future in mind? What are pros and cons? What do you recommed for .NET development? If I use 64 bit, can I run old .NET app?

Answer (score 0):

You can run any x86 application in win x64, too. If you want to use more then 3,2GB Ram, I strongly recommend x64. Assuming that all hardware in your system is as up to date as the i5, there would be no advantage of using x86.