# 32-bit or 64-bit OS?

Tags: linux, cpu, operating-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

I just built a new box which has an i7 3820 running as CPU.

I usually run linux distros on my boxes.  Is it best to go with a 64-bit distro with this model of CPU?  I would assume it is alright, since this is a powerful and newer CPU.

Also, I understand that programs built for 64-bit OSs are generally more powerful/faster.  Can someone clear this up for me if I have mistaken?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Just go 64 bit.

Comment: should have also mentioned i have an assLoad of ram...64 bit sounds good

Comment: my bad, i delete in 2 days

Comment: @beProactive - it's not necessary, it's just a duplicate. hopefully you found your answers in the other question.