# I'm running 32 bit lubuntu on this spec. Should I be using 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, computer-architecture, lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)

If so why?

Everything seems to work alright, but I wonder if it could cause problems down the road or I will not be getting the most out of my spec.

I don't really know a great deal about the differences between 64bit and 32 bit architectures.

Comment: I do not see any mentioned spec.

Comment: sorry about that! I meant to paste it in.

Comment: with that specs you should definitely switch to 64 bits. Are you joking? You got 8 GB RAM when 32 bit system can use up to 4 GB...

Comment: Haha yeah I just read the thread. I didn't go for it at first because the lubuntu install said amd on it but I see my foolishness now...

Comment: If you were adamant on using 32bit for some reason you could use a PAE kernel that would make use of your full 8 GB of memory