# 32bit os on a 64bit machine - what are the prices?

Tags: windows-7, performance, 64-bit

The it department installed a 32bit win7 on the I7 machine they are giving me.
I saw several questions asking here whether it is possible, which i now is the case, but I am still no clear about the prices.

Will the os or the programs I install, somehow  use only part of the resources of the machine?  Will I pay in performance for not having a 64bit os?

My RAM is 4gb and I plan to expand it to 6 or 8

p.s.
The 32bit os is already installed. So I am not asking what is generally better to do, but what are the prices and whether they worth bothering the IT to reinstall

edit: the question here [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems) relates to 64bit vs 32bit hardware and alsow touches the question of 32bit programs on a 64bti hardware. But it does not address the specific issue I ask here about: 32bit os on a 64bit architecture

Comment: If your mean is which is better for your system , absolutly 64bit. for example in win7 32bit your pc can be use just 2gig of your ram and win7 64bit is faster and use all of your system ...

Comment: This question has been asked before! Check for example http://superuser.com/q/56540/208234

Comment: Thanks Simon, the question you referred to is related but is not same. Please notice that the other question does not address the situation of 32bit os on a 64bits architecture which is what I ask about

Comment: @shealtiel: if you read the answers to the mentioned post, you will find as well answers to your question!

Comment: @Ramhound I think you wanted to address shealtiel.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have RAM above 3GB (which would be cut, since 32 bit Windows normally could only address around 3-3,75 GB depending on the RAM taken by VGA, soundcard etc), or apps that are optimized for 64 bit (obviously if you can run them, they do have 32 bit version but otherwise more optimized for 64 bit) such as Photoshop or video editing apps, then your PC would run just as good as any. If your RAM is under 3GB, running 64-bit could even be slower due to the overhead with the OS and the 32-bit emulation layer.
In my company 64-bit system usually have some quirk with old app or hardware (including shared printer), so while it could be solved, maybe your IT department just try to save some headache.

Comment: My RAM is 4gb and I plan to expand it to 6 or 8

Comment: Will only the OS itself under-use the RAM or also the programs that I'll install

Comment: Check System Properties, it would say 4GB RAM installed, XX GB usable. No matter how much RAM you install, as long as you use 32 bit OS it would be the maximum usable. All apps on the other hand would independently only use a max of 2 GB RAM.

Comment: You can use this http://wj32.org/wp/2012/12/26/pae-patch-updated-for-windows-8/ so Windows could address larger than 4GB RAM (still reduced by the amount of VGA and other device shared memory though), but each app would still only address 2 GB. Also note, upgrading to 64 bit won't make those apps magically address more than 2GB unless they have 64 bit version

Comment: Also, even if you eventually figure 64 bit is better for you, lack of driver or compatible app could make you the only one in the company to have trouble while other just run perfectly. Bothering the IT for new OS that potentially bother them again every other week is not worth it.