# How to install ubuntu without losing personal data?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I am quite new to Linux, I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop, currently running on Windows 10.

I am afraid to lose the personal files that I have on my local disk: F by default Windows is installed on Local Disk: C.

How to proceed with installation?

Do I need to partition the drives?

I am completely confused in the "Something Else" installation type in Ubuntu installer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your backups are complete, up-to-date and restorable. If you don't have backups, you should.

Comment: @gronostaj will the default Erase and install ubuntu affect any of my other drives (Like :F or :D)?

Comment: Well, if it says "erase", it will _erase_ them.

Comment: If you install Ubuntu on a drive or partition other than F, F will not be affected unless you mess up.  One way to ensure F is not affected is to temporarily disconnect it while you install Ubuntu (assuming it is a separate drive).

Comment: @fixer1234 Actually my pc is affected by a virus, Win32/ neshta.A so I believe installing a fresh ubuntu OS will help getting rid of it. I just don't want to lose any personal data. The drive is **not** separable.

Comment: Did you consider that a virus infection might be important information and context to share in the question?  If the system is infected, don't try to install something else; you will just have another thing to disinfect.  If you need another, clean OS to assist in cleaning this up, use a live session.  See this post for help getting rid of the virus: https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install ubuntu on my windows 8 laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/637567/install-ubuntu-on-my-windows-8-laptop)