# Why the process in Windows 64 bit only used 2GB of RAM?

Tags: windows, memory, process

To my knowledge, every process in Windows 32 bit only up to 2GB RAM. In Windows 64 bit longer, that number is much larger (about 8TB of RAM)

I write an application in C ++ that allows to use more than 2 GB of RAM (through dynamic allocation). but when run it only used up to 2GB RAM though I run Windows 64-bit machine.
Why is that?

Comment: Just running in 64-bit OS won't automatically turn the app into a 64-bit. It must be explicitly compiled as 64-bit app.

Comment: Thank you. i understand only 64-bit applications can use more than 2GB of RAM (not all applications on Windows 64-bit) 
and results of my C ++ compiler is a 32-bit applications

Comment: possible duplicate of [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](http://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems)